# Move-ADObject: Access is denied

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a script which should run as a service account.
Unchecking the "Protect from Accidental Deletion" is not the Problem because checked or unchecked I get the error: *Move-ADObject: Access is denied*. The script disables User/PC and creates the new OU.
The Service Account should not run as "domain admins". currently it has just "domain Users". Obviously, when I run as admin everything works but is there any solution that the script runs as a service account?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
##################################################
## Deactivate User and Move to another OU##
##################################################
$SAM = "KZerr"
$Path = "dc=aaa,dc=local"
$OUToSearchTheUser = "OU=Users," + $Path;

Disable-ADAccount -Identity $SAM

# Shows the disabled account
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled | ?{$_.SamAccountName -like $SAM}

########## CHECK IF OU EXITS, IF NOT CREATE ONE ##########
$OU = GET-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "DeactivatedUsers"' -SearchBase $OUToSearchTheUser
if($OU -eq $null){
 $NEWOU = NEW-ADOrganizationalUnit "DeactivatedUsers" –path $OUToSearchTheUser
}

#New-ADOrganizationalUnit -name DeactivatedUsers –path $OUToSearchTheUser
$UserNewPath = "ou=DeactivatedUsers,ou=Users," + $Path
Get-ADUser $SAM| Move-ADObject -TargetPath $UserNewPath

##################################################
            ##Deactivate Client Account ##
##################################################
$COMPUTERNAME = "TST1360"
$OUToSearchTheComputer = "OU=PC," + $Path;

Get-ADComputer -Identity $COMPUTERNAME | Disable-ADAccount 
# Shows the disabled account
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled | ?{$_.Name -like $COMPUTERNAME}

New-ADOrganizationalUnit -name DeactivatedComputers –path $OUToSearchTheComputer
$ComputerNewPath = "ou=DeactivatedComputers," + $OUToSearchTheComputer 
Get-ADComputer $COMPUTERNAME| Move-ADObject -TargetPath $ComputerNewPath
```

Comment: Does the service account have "Create child objects" permission on the `TargetPath` OU?

Comment: Yes. Create and delete child Objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The User and PC had : Descendant User Object and Descendant Computer Object.
The Problem was, I had to choose "this folder and subfolders permissions".